# No such element exception when reading from a text file

Tags: java, exception, io

I am trying to read in from a text file and use the data to resume a save game. The problem is however when it gets to the first line of code to read from the file it throws a no such element exception? Could anyone possibly give me a hint as to why this is happening. I've check the text file and data is there to read from.

Below is the code used:

```
public void readSave() {

            int p1Turn = 0;
            int p2Turn = 0;

            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("snorkels.txt");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                Scanner scan = null;

                int playerNumber = 0;


                while (line != null) {
                    scan = new Scanner(line);
                    playerNumber = scan.nextInt(); // No such element exception 

                    if (playerNumber == 1) {
                        player1.setName(scan.next());
                        player1.setColour(scan.next());
                        p1Turn = scan.nextInt();
                    }

                    if(playerNumber == 2){
                        player2.setName(scan.next());
                        player2.setColour(scan.next());
                        p2Turn = scan.nextInt();
                    }

                    line = reader.readLine();
                }


                reader.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldnae find the file");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Wee problem reading from file");
            }


        }
```

The exception is thrown when I try read the first int.

The text file contains this data:

1 jack P 0

2 AI G 0

Comment: That's an unreadable and unformatted wall of code. No-one will want to read that. Please go through [ask] and make a [mcve].

Comment: Use a debugger, put a breakpoint on the line, then view the value of `line`. It apparently doesn't contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is because of the file, you have an empty line between
**1 jack P 0** and **2 AI G 0**, so when your scanner is trying to get the nexInt of an empty line throws the exception.

Remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use a scanner to get your number.

You have the line of your save file as a string, you should get the different elements by splitting your string.

```
int playernumber = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
int turn = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[3]);
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I tried doing this but it also throws a no such element exception. I printed the contents of the line before splitting the string and it's exactly as I'd expect - "1 scott P 0". Very confused as to why "int playernumber = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);" causes an exception if the int's there to be read?